# Android color ProgressBar by textview

Tags: android, view, colors

I want to set the color of my ProgressBar getting the color of the TextView.
I have not found any documentation on this.
This is my TextView: `tv.setBackgroundColor(m.color);`
and this is my ProgressBar:

`int pr = (int)(value);
mProg = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress_e);
mProg.setMax(100);
mProg.setProgress(pr);`

how can I?

Answer (score 0):

```
tv.setBackgroundColor(m.color);

mProg.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(m.color,
android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

In case you want to retrieve the TextView's color, an easy way to do it would be to set its color as its tag, retrieve, parse it and use it as the ProgressBar's setColorFilter's parameter.

```
//to set it:
tv.setBackgroundColor(m.color);
tv.setTag(m.color);

//to retrieve it:
int color=Integer.parseInt(tv.getTag().toString());
mProg.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(color,
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: I did it with your code, From my logcat, the color is taken but the progressbar is still set to the default color.

Comment: What's the value of color?

Comment: example value of color:  -65463

Comment: I get a red ProgressBar using that color. Don't know why it doesn't work for you, sorry :/